# DecodeURIComponent not decoding %26 to &

Tags: javascript, jquery, encodeuricomponent, decodeuricomponent

I am trying to encode an ampersand using EncodeURIComponent and replace it with %26. The issue I am having is when I go to decode it using DecodeURIComponent it is displaying an "and". Here is my code. Anyone have any ideas what i am doing wrong?

```
if(e.keyCode == 13){
   var searchtab = getSearchParam($(this).parent().find(".search-tpe").val());
   $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/Search topic, title, author, A53/, ''));
       window.location  =  "/search/fullsite-search.html?query=" + decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent($(this).val().replace(/\\/g, '').replac\
e(/&/g,'%26'))) + "&" + getSearchParam($(this).parent().find(".search-type").val());
}
```

Comment: `replace(/&/g,'%26')` why are you doing this? `encodeUriComponent` will do it already..

Comment: Also please try to extract a runnable [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to describe the problem.